# Single Click reply to Approval Emails

Tags: force.com, email, email-template, approval-process, custom

Currently, to approve any salesforce record through email, you have to reply to approval email using Approved/Yes and it gets approve.

I just want to skip the step of writing "Approved/Yes" for approving records. Instead of this, I would like to create a HTML template and provide some button or link into that. When user will click the button or link, then it should approve that salesforce record ( make sure that button or link doesn't open a new salesforce window).

I don't know whether it's achievable or not, but I would like some positive response for this problem. Can anyone please suggest something ?

Answer (score 2):

A solution to this would be to publishing a Visualforce page on Salesforce Sites with the call to the API ro approve :
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_process.htm
The email link would open this page which will have an auto-init action call the approval.

To work without authentication, this could only be done on a custom object.

I hope this helps,
Rup

Comment: I don't want to open any new page. Can't we do it somehow without opening a new window/tab ?

Comment: This is an optimal solution.  I'm not sure if the Approval can be done by invoking a REST/SOAP resource, but still authentication would be a problem.  Or else you can close the page once the record is updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to not leave the mail message you're looking at and just have some sort of spinner that does all the work in the background; then that is very likely impossible in the most email clients (imagine the security impacts if mails could execute code).

You might be able to make a button in the HTML mail like

```
<a href="mailto:email@address.com?subject=YES. [Proper ID]&body=This is the body">Approve</a>
```

which opens a new email with the YES added to the subject? That saves a little typing, but I actually don't know if you can get hold of that response ID (or even response address) you need...

Otherwise, @altius_rup 's answer should work fine. The page can close itself once the approval is successful.